# Search for user by specific 12 digit ID number

Tags: 7, users, search

I'm building some functionality into a drupal 7 site that will let users search for another user, by a 12 digital identity number (for example: ZD-3423FGIO-XZ)

How would I go about doing this? Would I need to create some custom code to insert a new field in the user table that creates a custom number then modify the search functionality, or would I just use a module to do this?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me like a typical use case for Field UI and Views. No code needed.

Video tutorials on [Drupal 7](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/learn-drupal-7-with-nodeone), (Fields from episode 9), and [Views](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/taming-the-beast-learn-views-with-nodeone).

Comment: I've not used Field UI before, would you be kind enough to post a short sequence of events on how I might use this to solve my problem?

Comment: If you check out the docs on the field-ui and views that should give you a a fairly comprehensive run-down on how to implement it. http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/field-ui (Field-ui), and http://drupal.org/project/views